# How to fetch data when post the date is string in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my application i want to fetch the record on the bases of date i am posting the date like this (`2019-07-27`) and in my mongodb the date stores like (`"created_at" : ISODate("2019-07-27T16:01:24.636+05:00")`) but i return empty object how can i solve this problems any body help thanks in advance.
this is my mongodb data

http://prntscr.com/opi9lm

this is my post request

```
{
    "income_frequency" : "daily",
    "from_date" : "2019-07-27"
}
```

this is my controller

```
 const transactionsCredit = await driverTransactionModel.find( {
        $and: [
            { user_id: req.userData.userId },
            { transaction_type: mainConfig.transactionType.moneyIn },
            { created_at: req.body.from_date  }
        ]
    } ).lean().exec();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var from_date = new Date('2019-07-27'.toISOString());
db.collection.findOne('from_date': {
  $lte: from_date
}, function(err, doc) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log(doc);
  }
});
```

Note: You can convert date to ISODate and then find documents from collection will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 dates start date and end date and then match also in DB there's "created_at" which is in date format while date you received from the front end is in a string that's why you need to cast it to date first before matching in the query as

```
let startDate = new Date(req.body.from_date)
// this will give you date with utc time 00:00:00
let endDate = new Date(new Date(req.body.from_date).setUTCHours(23,59,59))
```

then match with start and end date in the query:

If you only want data of date of req.body.from_date

```
    const transactionsCredit = await driverTransactionModel.find( {
           user_id: req.userData.userId,
           transaction_type: mainConfig.transactionType.moneyIn,
           created_at:{$gte:startDate,$lte:endDate}).lean().exec();
```

If you want to fetch data greater than date(req.body.from_date)

```
     const transactionsCredit = await driverTransactionModel.find( {
           user_id: req.userData.userId,
           transaction_type: mainConfig.transactionType.moneyIn,
           created_at:{$gte:startDate}).lean().exec();
```